# Assign persistent MIDI Port to USB device?

Tags: alsa, udev, midi

Let's say that this device...

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1234:5678, ATTRS{manufacturer}=="SONY", ATTRS{product}=="61", DEVPATH==/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-2/2-2.1
```

...is currently assigned to *MIDI port 24:0*. How can I make this MIDI port assignment persistent so that it survives reboot, unplug/replug, etc.?

I've looked through all kinds of info on ALSA and UDEV but don't see anything useful about **MIDI port** assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the card ID permanent:

```
options snd-usb-audio index=2 vid=0x1234 pid=0x5678
```

(If you have other USB audio devices, you have to [add more options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices#https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices#Configuration) to ensure that the other devices do not occupy card index 2 first.)